# Sonata-Admin inline "add new button" resets all items

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

My inlines in Sonata-Admin got broken. When I click on "Add news" button, all inline fields are reloaded and replaced with empty values. I updated sonata-admin via composer, checked console for errors, but everything seems to be fine but it's not possible to add inlines anymore.

Here is FormMapper initialization:

```
    $formMapper
        ->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'Product title'))
        (...)
        ->add('images','sonata_type_collection', array('label' => 'Images'), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
        )) (...)
```

I also tried to update jquery.form.js as it was supposed on one of the forums, but unfortunately that didn't help as well.

This is original code for inline item:

```
 <td style="vertical-align: top;">
    <a href="/uploads/images/stool-01.jpg" target="_blank" class="full-img-link">/stool-01.jpg</a>
    <br>267.841 Kb, 2000x1333
    <br>Original file name: <b>Stool - 01.jpg</b>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label style="width:auto;padding-right:10px" class=" control-label" for="s567415498e56e_images_0_image_delete">Удалить</label>
        <div class="">
            <div class="icheckbox_minimal" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;"><input type="checkbox" id="s567415498e56e_images_0_image_delete" name="s567415498e56e[images][0][image][delete]" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins></div>                             
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

And here is new code which is sent over ajax request:

```
(..)                
<td class="sonata-ba-td-s5674144509ffc_images-_delete control-group">
   <input type="checkbox" id="s5674144509ffc_images_4__delete" name="s5674144509ffc[images][4][_delete]" value="1" />
</td>
<td class="sonata-ba-td-s5674144509ffc_images-image control-group">
  <div id="s5674144509ffc_images_4_image" class=""> 
     <input type="file" id="s5674144509ffc_images_4_image_file" name="s5674144509ffc[images][4][image][file]" class=" form-control" />
   </div>
</td>
(..)
```

Comment: Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how to ask a good question. Yours lack details, code, context, etc ....

Comment: @tchap thanks, updated record.